# Unable to get property 'stringify' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am getting this error after an AJAX call fails and I'm trying to log the error object by stringifying it and saving it to the sesssionStorage. The site is not in compatibility view or enterprise mode, it is IE11 and the doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the document mode is Edge and the user agent string is Default. This is only happening once in a blue moon so it's hard to track down what is happening. I haven't been able to get the error that is being thrown yet, however I will just create my own string that catches the details of the error that I need for now and then hopefully be able to move forward.

Has anyone else run into a situation where JSON should be available but isn't? Again, all the doctypes/compatibility settings are fine and this only happens once in a blue moon.

Answer (score 0):

Read about `stringify` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

The cause of your problem is that you try to call the `stringify` method of a variable which is a `null` reference or is `undefined`. To make sure this is not the case, validate your value to be a valid JSON:

```
function isNullOrUndefined(param) {
    return (!param);
}
```

then before you call stringify for foo:

```
if (!isNullOrUndefined(foo)) {
    //some code involving foo.stringify
}
```

Comment: I just created a jsfiddle that shows that this error does not come up if you pass null or undefined to it or a variable that is null or undefined: http://jsfiddle.net/gqzaaa4d/ - so I don't think that is the case. Also reading your answer further, I don't think you understand the problem. JSON is an object that is part of JavaScript, not an object that I created. It should be available in my circumstance.

Comment: Try this out: JSON = undefined; If you do that, you will see that it has a problem. I do not have your script, so I am assuming that somewhere a variable called JSON is used.

Comment: Nowhere are we setting JSON to be undefined. Also, if that was the case, this would happen continuously all over the place in our application. However, as mentioned, this happens once in a blue moon. (but thanks for trying).

Answer (score 0):

Apologies Steve,

I'd been having a noobs stringify issue and couldn't find a solution anywhere while getting the same error message. I'm happy to admit here, in the hope it can help others, **make sure you've updated to a recent version of jquery**, I'd been using version 1.4.1 shipped with VS2010, now using 2.1.3 with the help of NuGet packages.

Hope it doesn't go against the rules or offend you, but this really does feel like the best place to offer out this info even though I'm sure it is of little support to you.